# How to run custom domain under https?

Tags: ssl, https, digital-ocean, cname, custom-domain

I need some help to develop this solution in my application.

I have a domain **https://my-app-api.com** with SSL and there is running my application API.
Every customer who using my application can enter their own Custom Domain for example **customer-domain.com** and points his domain CNAME to **my-app-api.com**.

**Additional info**

My API running on Kubernetes cluster and using DigitalOcean services.

**Problem**

There is a problem with SSL certificates. Custom Domain that points to **my-app-api.com** runs only under HTTP not HTTPS. Everything must be done automatically over API. If customer enters a new custom domain and points CNAME to my app domain then I need to provide connection over HTTPS.

- How can I get it to run on HTTPS?
- Is zerossl.com solves that problem for me?
- Do I have to use Caddy or smth else?

Answer (score 0):

> customer domain --> CNAME --> your api

Is that correct?

> your API has SSL.

Is that correct?

> customer domain no SSL.

Is that correct?

If all answer is 'yes', the problem is, your customers.

Your customers need an SSL certificate for their domain, your had done all you need to do about SSL (for your API).

Your customers can use a service such as `zerossl.com`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution does not solve my problem. Is there a way to do it automatically? I have seen SaaS platforms where user enters their custom domain pointing CNAME to target domain and connection is provided over https.

Comment: You can ask your customers don't use their custom domain, use your domain instead.